# How to apply apply a focal filter to temperature data using information from a Digital Elevation Model in R software?

Tags: r, raster, spatial, temperature, terra

I have a temperature data raster and I want to utilize the focal function in R. However, before applying the focal function, I would like to examine if the surrounding pixels within a 5x5 window have similar elevation to the center cell, with a specified range of 100 meters, using digital elevation data. Only if this condition is met, I will proceed to run the focal filter on the temperature data.

Can you help with this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines

```
library(terra)
elevation <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
temp <- sqrt(elevation)

fe <- diff(focal(elevation, 5, range))
ft <- focal(temp, 5, mean)

x <- ifel(fe < 100, ft, temp)
```

---

In response to your comment:

> could we modify the filter to consider those pixels within the 5x5 window whose elevation difference from the center pixel is within 100m?

To use focal values from two layers, you can use `focalPairs`

```
f <- function(elv, tmp) {
    i <- which(abs(elv - elv[13]) < 100)
    mean(tmp[i])
}

z <- focalPairs(c(elevation, temp), 5, f)
```

Comment: Furthermore, instead of applying a 100m threshold to the entire 5x5 window, could we modify the filter to consider those pixels within the 5x5 window whose elevation difference from the center pixel is within 100m? This approach would potentially result in smoothing more temperature pixels compared to using a 100m threshold for the entire window.

Comment: Pls see my expanded answer

Comment: Great this is what I was looking for.  Now, I would like to further understand how the filling of values at the borders works when the fillvalue argument is set to NA.